# Resolve Variable in a Variable in shell

Tags: bash

I have to use environment vars in my `bash` shell and:

- `echo $ENV` resolves to `DEV`, `STAGE` or `PRD` depending upon the stack.
- `echo $DEV_ACCOUNT` resolves to a number e.g. `echo $DEV_ACCOUNT` gives `12345678`

I need to use `echo $ENV_ACCOUNT` in a command which should resolve to `12345678` but it is resolving to `DEV_ACCOUNT` instead of `12345678`.

The command I am using:

```
aws events put-targets --rule {{ stack_name | lower }}-hello-world \
    --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:$ENV_ACCOUNT:function:hello-world"
```

The `$ENV_ACCOUNT` is resolving to `DEV_ACCOUNT` instead of `12345678`.
The expected output is:

```
aws events put-targets --rule {{ stack_name | lower }}-hello-world \
    --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:12345678:function:hello-world"
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Also provide the command where you are using ENV_ACCOUNT.

Comment: And where (and to what) are you setting `ENV_ACCOUNT`?

Comment: @P_Yadav aws events put-targets --rule {{ stack_name | lower }}-hello-world --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:$ENV_ACCOUNT:function:hello-wolrd" This is the command where i want to resolve the account number.

Comment: @Bharat please edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that uppercase variable names are not generally safe to use.  `$ENV`, for example, is special in many shells.  In these shells, its value should be the pathname of a file that will be sourced before starting certain types of shells.  The `bash` shell uses `$ENV` in POSIX mode.

So, in `bash`:

```
declare -A account
account["develop"]=12345678
account["staging"]=9128312
account["production"]=123123

mode=$run_mode

aws events put-targets \
    --rule {{ stack_name | lower }}-hello-world \
    --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:${account[$mode]}:function:hello-wolrd"
```

This sets up an associative array, `account`, that holds the data for development, staging and production modes.  It then defines the mode that we're using and executes the command with the correct data from the `account` array.  The `run_mode` variable is assumed to be an environment variable containing one of the strings `develop`, `staging` or `production`.

Associative arrays were introduced in `bash` 4.0.

I have used your `aws` command as you wrote it (except for adding newlines and my `account` variable), even though the `{{ stack_name | lower }}-hello-world` probably does not de what you'd expect it to (it would try to execute `lower` as a command).  Since I don't know `aws`, I don't know what it should look like, but it should probably be quoted.

---

Addressing [user mosvy's concerns in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492182/resolve-variable-in-a-variable-in-shell/492186?noredirect=1#comment903617_492186):  In the case where the variables `DEV_ACCOUNT` etc. are environment variables and the correct one has to be picked based on what the `ENV` variable is:

```
declare -A account
account["DEV"]=$DEV_ACCOUNT
account["STAGE"]=$STAGE_ACCOUNT
account["PRD"]=$PRD_ACCOUNT

mode=$ENV

# the rest as before
```

Comment: Thanks for telling about arrays. Is there any other way to resolve the variable ?
I tried the arrays using vars, but not successful. Instead of strings,

declare -A account
account["$ENV"]="$ENV_ACCOUNT"

Didn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Bharat I don't think I ever used a variable while setting the values in the `account` array in my code. The `account` array is an array of static values for the three types `develop`, `staging` and `production`.  The `mode` variable then controls which one of these that will be used.

Comment: @Bharat don't ignore the advice about not using CAPS, it is important. And please read this answer again, he isn't suggesting `declare -A account account["$ENV"]="$ENV_ACCOUNT"`.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer the question *as it was set*. The first line says 'I have to use environment vars' but this answer goes on with an array solution which completely ignores that requirement. I cannot claim to know OP's actual problem, but please consider a situation where `DEV_ACCOUNT`, `STAGE_ACCOUNT`, etc. are given in the environment, their names cannot be changed, and the script has to choose and expand one of them based on a argument or another environment variable.

Comment: @mosvy See updated answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for your detail explanation about the arrays and how to use them.  It worked in my environment.

Answer (score 2):

I will repeat what Kusalananda [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492186/22222) about not using ALLCAPS for variable names in shell scripts. That is generally a bad idea and can cause issues when your variable names collide with default environment variables. And I also agree that the best way to do this is to use an associative array as he describes in his answer.

In any case, if you insist on doing it this (wrong) way instead of using an array, you will need to do something like this:

```
varname="$env"_account
aws events put-targets --rule {{ stack_name | lower }}-hello-world \
    --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:${!varname}:function:hello-world"
```

The `${!var}` syntax will expand to the value of a variable named `var`. For example:

```
$ foo="foovar"
$ bar=foo
$ echo ${!bar}
foovar
```

Seriously though, just don't do this. It is complicated, cumbersome, hard to read, harder to maintain and an associative array will just solve all of these issues for you.

Comment: Why is `$ENV_ACCOUNT` being parsed as `${ENV}_ACCOUNT` instead of `${ENV_ACCOUNT}`? Is it because `$ENV` is special? (Or is that sufficiently interesting that it's better as a new question?)

Comment: @roaima um. Because the OP said it did, so I assumed it was being treated as I described? I admit I just assumed that's what was happening without giving it much thought. Now that you mention it, I have no idea how the OP could have gotten this behavior instead of `$ENV_ACCOUNT` being empty.

Comment: @roaima I was assuming it was a mistyping in the question, or that they, at some point, set `ENV_ACCOUNT` to the string `DEV_ACCOUNT` and forgot about it. It was unimportant to answering the question (or so I thought).

Comment: @KusalanandaI haven't set the ENV_ACCOUNT to DEV_ACCOUNT. I had set DEV_ACCOUNT=12345678 as ENV

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everyone who posted solutions to my question. I had implemented bash arrays to solve my problem. But,My friend suggested a simple solution to it

```
printenv `echo $ENV`_ACCOUNT
```

solved my problem.

Comment: Just printing the variable's value "solved it"?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah, My main intention was to resolve the value of the variable. I redirected the output of "printenv `echo $ENV`_ACCOUNT" to var and used that var in the command. But, thanks to you for telling about the bash arrays.